Infinite-round function evaluation
Assume there are two parties $A$ and $B$.

$A$ executes a program with memory $x$;
as $A$'s memory changes over time,
I use $x_t$ to denote it for time $t$.
$B$ holds a program invariant $\phi: X \to \{ 0,1 \}$;
I use $X$ to denote the set of all possible $x$'s.

My goal is to have $A$ and $B$ evaluate $\phi(x_t)$
for all $t$ (i.e., infinitely many times),
without $A$ learning $\phi$ and $B$ learning $x_t$ for any $t$.
$A$ and $B$ halt if the invariant evaluates to $0$,
and reiterate otherwise.
Assume that $A$ violates $\phi$ once
if and only if $A$ violates $\phi$ infinitely many times.
I know about (reactive) private function evaluation.
In the ideal model of (reactive) PFE,
a trusted third party receives $x_t$ and $\phi$
and returns $\phi(x_t)$ to $B$.
There is an easy cheat
if $A$ is not honest, and $\phi(x_1)$ holds:
in all rounds $t > 1$,
$A$ sends $x_1$ instead of $x_t$,
as she knows that $\phi(x_1)$ holds.
I emphasise that this problem exists in the ideal model.
This problem may be resolved in two ways:

Relaxing the halting criterion:
I let $B$ 'skip' some rounds with non-zero probability;
this way, if the loop continues for more than one iteration,
$A$ cannot be sure that $\phi(x_1)$ was true.
The issue is that I cannot see how this can be extended
to infinitely many iterations.
$A$ convinces $B$ that $x_{t+1}$ is
the successor of $x_t$ after one step of the program.
The issue with this method is mainly scalability;
I do not know an efficient way of doing this.
Please keep in mind
that $A$'s program should also be kept private from $B$.

Does (a modified form of) any of these methods solve the issue?
If not, is there a different way to obtain the same goal?

This is a classic issue in secure computation sometimes referred to "input substitution". I.e., the problem of ensuring that an adversary uses the "correct" input to the function being computed. If this issue is present in your ideal functionality, it basically just means your ideal functionality is not capturing the properties you require, and you should adjust it. I.e., in your case your ideal functionality should somehow check $x_t$ is correctly computed from $x_{t-1}$. This in turn should lead to a solution similar to your second suggestion for a solution.
